# compare sources from git and mercurial repositories and synchronize them

Tags: git, github, mercurial, repository

In our project due to the way of team operating and corporate security policy the same codebase hosted inside 2 repositories, one is `git`, 2nd is `mercurial` and one part of the team  normally committing to `mercurial` repo, 2nd part commit to `git`.

Because of such a strange way of operating with some time codebase in 2 repos stop being synchronized, and I need to make it sync again.

So initially I have 2 questions:

1. How to compare sources from Git and Mercurial
2. How to synchronize them.

---

UPD1: In case of synchronization, I don't think it's need to be super advanced, e.g. have the same commit's history or something like that. If it's just will put files in the same state (where possible, manual merging in other case) - that's will be more than completely fine.

Comment: Hopefully you created these repositories such that they have an existing relationship, e.g. using [`hg-git`](http://hg-git.github.io/) to create a Mercurial repository from a Git one. Is this the case, or are they entirely independent?

Comment: It was a part of large git repository at the start. Than some libs was extracted and mercurial repositories for them created. Don't think hg-git was used (don't know for sure, wasn't part of the project at that time).

Comment: [hggit](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git) to pull/push change sets to/from hg and then merge?

Answer (score 1):

To compare the sources, you could clone the mercurial and the git repo in your computer, and use `diff` on those directories. For example:

```
diff -rq git_repo hg_repo | grep -v .git | grep -v .hg
```

The synchronisation part is harder: it depends on what you want to do in cases where the code diverged between the two. I guess you can do it manually using the list of diffs generated previously, but I can't think of a more automated way.